# How to Power off or shutdown XenDesktop Command?

Tags: powershell, citrix, vdi, xendesktop

I want to shut down or Power Off Citrix Xendesktop.

I tried many sites including [Citrix docs](https://docs.citrix.com) but couldn't find anything for shutting down the Xendesktop.

Comment: You mean like `shutdown /m \\COMPUTERNAME /t 0 /f`?

Comment: yes, will that work in the case of xendesktop as well ?

Comment: You tell me. Go try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the Cmdlet to Power off the XenDesktop.

The command is `New-BrokerHostingPowerAction -Action Shutdown -MachineName "$domain_name\$machine_name'`.

In above command one needs to supply the domain and machine name to poweroff/shutdown the xendesktop from Powershell.

[Reference](https://docs.citrix.com/zh-tw/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-5/cds-sdk-wrapper-rho/cds-sdk-cmdlet-help/citrix-broker-admin-v2-wrapper-xd75/new-brokerhostingpoweraction-xd75.html)